# how to create a copyable macro in excel that jumps 4 down for each copy

Tags: excel, copy, formulas

I have a long list of steps and a time per step, I want to aggregate the time for each run like you see in the image below.

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lzTp.png)

so, for the F column I would like to be able to drag downwards and get the following:

```
=SUM(B2:B5)
=SUM(B6:B9)
=SUM(B10:B13)
.
.
.
```

Is there a way to do this in Excel?

Comment: Could you not just do a SUMIF based on the run part of Column A? Then if you had more or less steps than 4 in a run you'd be covered.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, sod it, I'll give you the answer, F2 is:

`=SUMIF($A$2:$A$13,E2&" *",$B$2:$B$13)`